# How to program around lack of 'friends' capability in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have 3 classes, one controller object `Controller` and two model objects `Foo` and `Bar`.

Let's say that `Foo` and `Bar` have a `stop` method, which is intended only ever to be invoked by a `Controller` method, and not called directly by other classes.

How can I make it so that if any other class calls `stop` directly on either `Foo` and `Bar`, they get (ideally) a compile time warning or (next best) a runtime warning?

Note, this is to stop accidentally calling the wrong method, rather than something that needs to be secure. The `stop` methods can be rewritten if needs be, but it would be nice not to have to.

My current ideas are:

1) Define a `Controller` category on `Foo` and `Bar`, and move the stop method there. Put this in a separate file so you have to go out of your way to import it (however this will not result in a compile warning if someone does it anyway - but at least should make it clearer that this is not the expected way to use the class)

2) Add a `sender` parameter to the methods and check that this is of type [Controller class] at runtime.

But neither of these seem ideal as they are both a little error prone. Is there a better objective-c pattern for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a category (e.g: `@interface Foo (Friends)`) in a separate file in which you declare the methods that can be used only by the `Controller`.

Foo+Friends.h:

```
@interface Foo (Friends)
-(void)stop;
@end
```

Foo+Friends.m or Foo.m:

```
#import "Foo+Friends.h"
@implementation Foo (Friends)
-(void)stop{
    // implementation for stop
}
@end
```

In the files where you import "Foo+Friends.h" (in your case `Controller.m`) you can access the `stop` method without any warning.

Comment: yes this is probably what I'll do - it is basically my point 1) above. Would be cool if there was a way to (compiler) warn about including the file in other than Controller.m tho.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to throw an exception unconditionally in the `-stop` method. Code calling that method properly will catch the exception and ignore it; code that calls it naively won't expect the exception and will likely crash with an uncaught exception error.

I'm not crazy about throwing an exception when nothing is really wrong, but here you're concerned that something *might* be wrong, so it's not terrible.

A better option would be to think about why you want to restrict use of `-stop` to the Controller class and try to refactor your code to avoid that. Model objects shouldn't have to know anything about the controllers that use them, so eliminating this dependency would seem a good idea.